# How do I draw a curve in sculpt mode on my object

Tags: sculpting

I want to draw a curve in sculpt mode on my object, using the crease tool.

I’m in sculpt mode

I ve selected the

crease brush
Curve stoke

I now can’t seem to draw curve or draw a curve on the object.

Am I missing a hot key first??

Comment: Hello, have you subdivided your object or enabled Dyntopo?

Answer (score 2):

In Sculpt mode, go to the Stroke menu and change it to `curve`, `new`, and press `draw` curve.
[image]

Then press `control`+ `right mouse button` and drag the line.

Pressing `shift` and right clicking on points will allow you to edit the handles.

[image]

Press `enter` when you are finished the curve.